# Expunge causes the renumbering of Message objects subsequent to the expunged messages

Tags: jakarta-mail

From [javamail MailFolder class doc](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html) I read this:

> Note that a Message's message number can change within a session if
>   the containing Folder is expunged using the expunge method. Clients
>   that use message numbers as references to messages should be aware of
>   this and should be prepared to deal with situation (probably by
>   flushing out existing message number references and reloading them).
>   Because of this complexity, it is better for clients to use Message
>   objects as references to messages, rather than message numbers.
>   Expunged Message objects still have to be pruned, but other Message
>   objects in that folder are not affected by the expunge.

I would like to know how could I use Message objects as reference to messages if they change, I mean that even if I store Message objects references before deletion, once a MessageCount REMOVED event comes, the object reference is different from the one stored before.

I'm asking this because I had actually issues using message number as reference for deleted messages... so I'm considering to rebuild entirely Map of  for every REMOVED event.
I don't like very much this approach because I think it could be slowly in huge mailboxes... but I can't see the light in using messageNumber...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Message object references don't change when messages are expunged.  The Message object that referenced message number 17 might now reference message number 15, but it will be the same **message** on the server.

Obviously Message object references are only valid as long as the JVM is running, and only as long as the Folder is open.  If you need a long term reference for a message, you need to learn about IMAP UIDs; see the [UIDFolder](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html) interface and the [IMAP RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3501.txt).

Comment: Thanks Bill, yes my application is always running listening for any events, either added or removed, so I need a long term reference.
Until now I loaded a Map on startup referencing every message number with its relative UID, so for any removed event, starting from message number of removed event I could get the UID to find message in my database.
For what I understand, you are suggesting to not use at all message numbers and to use only UID via UIDFolder, am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: Message numbers are convenient to work with when the folder is open, but they're are only valid as long as the folder is open.  If you close the folder or the server closes the folder for you, you have to forget about message numbers.  UIDs are still valid after the folder is closed and reopened, but you have to resynchronize your view of the messages at that point.  Doing this correctly is tricky.  So, you should definitely use UIDs, but you can also use message numbers as long as you understand the limitations.

Comment: Thanks @Bill, just a last question, when you say _but you have to resynchronize your view of the messages at that point_ are you thinking about the UIDValidity matter? That is the possibility that one day, all uids are not more valid so they need to be resync? Otherwise what do you mean with that sentence? Thanks

Comment: you definitely need to consider UIDValidity, but I was talking about the fact that messages can be added or expunged while the folder is closed and if you're caching information about the messages you'll need to update that cache when the folder is next opened.